# Prolog print all possible Lists

Tags: list, prolog

I am trying to print out every possible list for a given variable. With native functions, this is working fine, but as soon as I do this with lists, prolog throws an exception.

This is my code (simplified):

```
first(A, L) :- L = [K|_], A = K.                % First element of L is A
second(A, L) :- L = [_|R], R=[F|_], A = F.      % Second element of L is A
third(A, L) :- L = [_|R], second(A, R).         % Third element of L is A

konst(S) :- first(X, S), second(Y,S), third(Z,S), X >= 0, Y >= 0, Z >= 0, X =< 3, Y =< 4, Z =< 5.

| ?- konst(S).
uncaught exception: error(instantiation_error,(>=)/2)
```

So basically it should print out every single list between [0,0,0] and [3,4,5].

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Add: The list should be exactly 3 items long - probably I need to define this somehow.

Comment: See e.g. https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=nth0/3  Debugging is an essential skill, using e.g. `trace` and `gtrace` - https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=debugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definition just speaks about lists but does not define that the values are numbers. In particular, the arithmetic predicates like `=<` can only compare concrete numbers: `1 =< 2` succeeds but `X =< 2` leads to the instantiation error you found.

To solve your problem you can use the predicate `between/3` that succeeds if the range given by the first two arguments covers the third:

```
p([A,B,C]) :-
  between(0, 3, A),
  between(0, 4, B),
  between(0, 5, C).
```

Then the query

```
?- p([A,B,C]), A < 1, B < 1, C < 1.
A = B, B = C, C = 0 ;
false.
```

works as expected. This is due to the limitations of Prolog's built-in arithmetic. If you want to go beyond that the keyword is (finite) constraint logic programming (CLP). One of the Prolog libraries for that is [clp(Z)](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/clpz).

Comment: Okay. This is woking fine, but now I get a different error when ensuring the sum of the list has a certain value (0 in this case):

```
konst(S) :- first(X, S), second(Y,S), third(Z,S), between(0, 3, X), between(0, 4, Y), between(0, 5, Z).

run(V) :- konst(V), sum_list(V, S), between(0, 0, S).

---
| ?- run(V).
V = [0,0,0] ? ;
uncaught exception: error(instantiation_error,(is)/2)
```

So, I get a single solution [0,0,0] and then it errors out..

Comment: You have an additional predicate `sum_list` which probably contains the `is` throwing the error. It might be better to open a new question for that. But my guess is that your `konst/1` predicate allows lists of arbitrary length( `first(X,S), second(Y,S), third(Z,S).` gives the answer `S = [X, Y, Z|_22664].`). In that case the sum predicate would need to add unknown values again. Perhaps try with `S = [A,B,C], konst(V), sum_list(V, S).`? The `V` should be computable via `S` such that you don't need a `between` for that.

Comment: In normal Prolog, `<=` is **not** "less than or equal; it is `=<`. OP wrote it correctly and you wrote it wrong in your answer, three times.

Comment: Indeed, I wrote that part without testing it. Fixed now, thank you.